# SQL to find records with last 3 same status

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have the following tasks table:

```
id  type   submit_time   status
```

I need to run a query that returns only the types which their last 3 tasks finished with status "FAILED".

How can I do this?
Should I use a window function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and filtering after using `row_number()` to get the last three rows:

```
select type
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by submit_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by type
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'FAILED' and
       count(*) = 3;
```

Actually, a slightly simpler method is:

```
select type
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by submit_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3 and status = 'FAILED'
group by type
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: @IdoBarash . . . The first query should also work now.  It had a misplaced parenthesis.